# Are questions related to TCL code on topic?

Tags: discussion

Are questions related to TCL **code** on topic? I'm referring to questions like "How to do this with TCL?" or "How to improve this TCL code?" or "This piece of code does not work" etc.

Of course I'm referring to the Cisco devices and EEM.

Comment: Could you tell us more about the use case?  Do you mean TCL running on a Cisco router, or TCL running on a linux/windows machine (to scrape text from a router)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "How to do this with TCL?" or "How to improve this TCL code?"
>   Of course I'm referring to the Cisco devices and EEM.

Assuming all are on a Cisco router (or some other on-topic platform)... these seem like reasonable questions

- *How to do this with TCL* ([one example](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/7495/775) of an on-topic question involving TCL on Cisco IOS)
- *How to fix this TCL code?*
- *How to improve the performance / reliability of this TCL code?*